# Eclipse indigo JSP shows 'HTTP Status 404:requested resource()not available' when run on tomcat7

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-404, tomcat7, eclipse-indigo

I have **Tomcat 7.0.14**, **jdk 1.6** and **Eclipse Indigo** for Java EE web app developers.

I tested Tomcat with a simple project with html and jsp files. When I run each file, I get the correct output in the working space. But when I reconfigured the server to include my project and clicked run `main.html`, it only shows

```
The requested resource (/Prisonhome/main.jsp) is not available.
HTTP Status 404.
```

What could be missing?
I have `Prisonhome` in the same directory as the other simple hello project. I've also copied the `web.xml` file to `WEB_INF` and `WEB_INF/lib`.
I haven't configured any `xml` files, since this is not just a servlet program, but `jsp`.

Comment: Is the mention of main.HTML in the workspace and a missing main.JSP intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever solved this already, but I thought I'd post a reply for anyone else having issues.

I encountered this same problem, but noticed that if I configured a project for Tomcat 6.0.32 instead, the project hosted without issues. I eventually realized that the **Dynamic Web Module** version was actually the problem, and **needed to be set to 2.5** (http://i.imgur.com/09d6A.png) or else all the pages would resolve as 404s .

Once I created a new project with the module set to 2.5, I could host on both Tomcat 6 and 7. Tomcat 7 is supposed to support module 3.0, but I don't think it is fully working yet in eclipse.

Comment: Tomcat 6 is a Servlet 2.5 container which thus doesn't support Servlet 3.0. It would simply fail to deploy a Servlet 3.0 targeted WAR (which could be confirmed by reading the server startup logs). That was your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I was trying to say I had no issues with Tomcat 6 **because** it forced me to use Servlet 2.5. It was after I successfully hosted the same project on the Tomcat 7 that I realized Tomcat 7 would also work, but only if I elected to use Servlet 2.5 instead of 3.0.